# ASP.NET Web API versioning with URL Query gives "duplicate route" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, versioning

First, a little disclaimer: I have already created a GitHub issue for this at the [aspnet-api-versioning repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/326). The content of this question is basically the same as the content in that github issue.

I am using ASP.NET Web API on .NET 4.5.2.

My example API looks like this:

```
namespace App.Backend.Controllers.Version1
{
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    public class SomeController: ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/entity/{id:int:min(1)}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ApiAction(int id) //Already running in production
        {
            //Accessible by using ?api-version=1.0 OR by omitting that since this is the default version
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}

namespace App.Backend.Controllers.Version2
{
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    public class SomeController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/entity/{id:int:min(1)}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ApiAction(int id)
        {
            //Accessible by using ?api-version=2.0 OR by omitting that since this is the default version
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

The config is as follows:

```
// Add versioning
config.AddApiVersioning(o => 
{
    o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
});
```

When I send a request, though, the following happens:

`System.InvalidOperationException: A route named 'RegisterHours' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.`

**Duplicates:**

api/some/ApiAction
api/some/ApiAction

This is weird to me because in the wiki [there is an example](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Versioning-via-the-Query-String) **exactly** like my situation

I'd like to use the `?api-version={version}` option but it looks I have no choice to use the URL path version now (`api/v1.0/some/apiAction` and `api/v2.0/some/apiAction`. If that's true, I guess I have to add another Route to every existing action which will be like `api/v{version:apiVersion}/controller/action` to allow them to use `v1.0` so it will be uniform in the entire application?

What do you guys advise? I could just use `/v2.0/` in the URL of version 2 of the API I guess, but I'd prefer the query string version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't show it in the example, but the error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A route named 'RegisterHours' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.

means that there are multiple entries with the same name in the route table. If I had to guess, the attribute routes are actually being defined as:

```cs
[Route("api/entity/{id:int:min(1)}", Name = "RegisterHours")]
```

...or something like that.

Unfortunately, the route table is **not** API *version-aware*. The names in the route table **must** be unique. When you specify the name in the **RouteAttribute**, it causes this issue. The only real way around it is to use unique route names; for example, `Name = "RegisterHoursV1"` and `Name = "RegisterHoursV2"`.

**Aside:** you don't need:

```cs
var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver()
{
    ConstraintMap = { ["apiVersion"] = typeof( ApiVersionRouteConstraint ) }
};
configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes( constraintResolver );
```

**unless** you are versioning by URL segment.

Answer (score 0):

After you have fixed the duplicate "RegisterHours" (as per the git hub issues page responses) you should also ensure you have the constraintResolver setup in your startup.cs

```
    public void Configuration( IAppBuilder builder )
    {
        // we only need to change the default constraint resolver for services that want urls with versioning like: ~/v{version}/{controller}
        var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver() { ConstraintMap = { ["apiVersion"] = typeof( ApiVersionRouteConstraint ) } };
        var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
        var httpServer = new HttpServer( configuration );

        // reporting api versions will return the headers "api-supported-versions" and "api-deprecated-versions"
        configuration.AddApiVersioning( o => o.ReportApiVersions = true );
        configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes( constraintResolver );
        builder.UseWebApi( httpServer );
    }
```

Otherwise your attributes to change the route (api/entity) won't work because the route doesn't match the controller name "Some" and so won't match the default routing ie. ~\api\controllername\

```
public class ***Some***Controller : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route( "api/***entity***/{id:int:min(1)}" )]    <--- won't work without the constraint resolver
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ApiAction( int id )
    {
        //Accessible by using ?api-version=2.0 OR by omitting that since this is the default version
        return Ok();
    }
```